# Using Android maps.jar GeoPoint on JBoss 7: java.lang.RuntimeException: stub

Tags: android, google-maps, exception, jboss7.x, geopoints

I'm new about posting answers on stackoverflow. I hope you can help me.

I'm developing an Android app using Google Maps.
It calls a JBOSS 7 server via HTTP REST, this server calls another server via HTTP REST to get some points from some Open Data.
Then when the first server gets the response it have to prepare data for the smartphone client.
So it prepares an array list of  OverlayItem, using GeoPoint.
But it has an exception when creating GeoPoint.

I have put maps.jar and gson-2.2.2.jar in /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ and it seems that it works but I'm not so expert about Java and JBoss and don't know if it's right.

This is the exception in the JBoss console:

> 11:36:23,287 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Prototipo_server_2].[it.unifi.sistemiTelematici.BikeServer.Rest.BikeServerREST]]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet
>   it.unifi.sistemiTelematici.BikeServer.Rest.BikeServerREST threw
>   exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: stub  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_09] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: stub     at
>   com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint.(Unknown Source) [maps.jar:]
>     at
>   it.unifi.sistemiTelematici.BikeServer.Rest.ServiziRastrelliere.getRastrelliereList(ServiziRastrelliere.java:100)
>   [classes:]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]     ... 19 more

and this is the code of the class that give the exception:

```
package it.unifi.sistemiTelematici.BikeServer.Rest;

import it.unifi.sistemiTelematici.BikeServer.JSON.JSONArray;
import it.unifi.sistemiTelematici.BikeServer.JSON.JSONException;
import it.unifi.sistemiTelematici.BikeServer.JSON.JSONObject;
import it.unifi.sistemiTelematici.BikeServer.Utils.CoordinatesUtilities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

@Path("/ServiziRastrelliere")
public class ServiziRastrelliere {

    private RestComuneFirenze restComune;
    private CoordinatesUtilities CoordinatesUtilities;

    public ServiziRastrelliere() {

        restComune = new RestComuneFirenze();
        CoordinatesUtilities = new CoordinatesUtilities();

    }

    JSONArray rastrelliereFeatures = null;


    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/RastrelliereList/{latitudine}/{longitudine}")
    public String getRastrelliereList(@PathParam("latitudine") String latitudine, @PathParam("longitudine") String longitudine){

        String rastrelliereListJSON = null;

        JSONObject rastrellieraObj, rastrellieraGeometryObj, rastrellieraPropertiesObj;
        JSONArray rastrellieraCoordinates;
        double rastrellieraCoordX, rastrellieraCoordY;
        int rastrellieraCoordXint, rastrellieraCoordYint;
        String rastrellieraPostiString, rastrellieraLocalizzazione, rastrellieraModello;

        List<OverlayItem> myOverlayItemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        Type listOfMyOverlayItemType = new TypeToken<List<OverlayItem>>(){}.getType();

        rastrelliereFeatures = restComune.getRastrelliereList(latitudine, longitudine);

        if (rastrelliereFeatures != null) {

            try {

                for (int i = 0; i < rastrelliereFeatures.length(); i ++) {

                    rastrellieraObj = rastrelliereFeatures.getJSONObject(i);
                    rastrellieraGeometryObj = rastrellieraObj.getJSONObject("geometry");

                    rastrellieraCoordinates = rastrellieraGeometryObj.getJSONArray("coordinates");
                    rastrellieraCoordX = rastrellieraCoordinates.getDouble(0);
                    rastrellieraCoordY = rastrellieraCoordinates.getDouble(1);
                    rastrellieraCoordXint = CoordinatesUtilities.fromJSONtoItemCoord(rastrellieraCoordX);
                    rastrellieraCoordYint = CoordinatesUtilities.fromJSONtoItemCoord(rastrellieraCoordY);

                    rastrellieraPropertiesObj = rastrellieraObj.getJSONObject("properties");

                    rastrellieraPostiString = rastrellieraPropertiesObj.get("NUMPOSTI").toString();
                    rastrellieraLocalizzazione = rastrellieraPropertiesObj.getString("LOCALIZZAZIONE");
                    rastrellieraModello = rastrellieraPropertiesObj.getString("MODELLO");

                    //myOverlayItemList.add(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(rastrellieraCoordYint, rastrellieraCoordXint), rastrellieraLocalizzazione, "Modello = " + rastrellieraModello + "Posti: " + rastrellieraPostiString));

                    System.out.println("rastrellieraCoordYint = " + rastrellieraCoordYint + " rastrellieraCoordXint = " + rastrellieraCoordXint);

                    //myOverlayItemList.add(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(rastrellieraCoordYint, rastrellieraCoordXint), "a", "b"));

                    GeoPoint geopoint = new GeoPoint(43770262, 11252829);

                    //myOverlayItemList.add(new OverlayItem( new GeoPoint(43770262, 11252829), "Access Title 1", "Access snippet 1"));

                }

            } catch (JSONException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            } 

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            rastrelliereListJSON = gson.toJson(myOverlayItemList, listOfMyOverlayItemType);

        } else {

            rastrelliereListJSON = "error";

        }

        return rastrelliereListJSON;

    }


}
```